# SQL query to search for longest common prefixes

Tags: mysql, search, prefix

In my database I have a table PRODUCT with a VARCHAR(255) column PRODNAME. In that column I store all my product names.

Now I've got to implement a simple search engine looking at that column. I'd like to use the LIKE statements as an exact match == over strings would be too restrictive but I want to match only prefixes inside the text of column PRODNAME. How to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: VARCHAR(255) of course. thank you for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wildcard (percent sign), ie.

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODNAME LIKE 'prefix%'`

To search for all substrings, use:

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODNAME LIKE '%substring%'`

Or suffixes:

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODNAME LIKE '%suffix'`

Comment: that'ok but what when it comes to search for prefixes over natural language text? Does the LIKE operand works over space characters?

Comment: Yes, it does, provided you add a wildcard after the space.  Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: here my query: select * from product where prodname LIKE "*<token0>%" OR prodname LIKE "*<token1>%" ... where <token0>,<token1> etc.. are the text tokens computed from the actual string the user entered in the search from

Comment: NOt sure why the asterisk is added prior to your tokens, but yes, you would take the user input as a variable and use that to build your query.